# Display block property is not working wants div below other div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, div1 and div2. I wanted div2 below div1 because I have used position absolute property in div1. Div2 is going above div1

I wanted to use position absolute because I wants to position div1 at bottom left corner

```css
.home {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  top: 50%;
  left: 8px;
  padding: 33px 23px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.about {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">div1</div>
<div class="about">div2</div>
```

Comment: Just don't use `position: absolute` in this case.

Comment: *"I wanted to use position absolute because I wants to position content of div1 at bottom left corner"* - That's not what position absolute does and there are better methods

Comment: sounds like you want to use `position: fixed` to achieve a position fixed in relation to the viewport/window. In this case don't use the `top`, but the `bottom` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the `div1` in lower left corner, and want `div2` below the `div1`, then:

- you can enclose the 2 divs in another div, and have the `position: absolute;` for that div
- and also, instead of `top: 50%;`, you can have `bottom: 0`.

  - This will make sure that, the parent div is placed exactly at the bottom left corner (and not on left edge).
- And you can remove the `position: absolute;` from `div1`.

  - This way, you can be sure that `div2` will appear below `div1`, as both these divs will not have position set as absolute, and they will appear relative to each other.

```css
.home {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 33px 23px;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.about {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.bottomLeft {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomLeft">
    <div class="home">div1</div>
    <div class="about">div2</div>
</div>
```

Edit 1: Modified `top: 50%;` to `bottom: 0;`, and improved formatting.

Answer (score -1):

To immediately solve your problem, I would suggest wrapping both of these divs in another element, then positioning that new outer element absolutely at the bottom left:

```
.container {
  /* position in the bottom left*/
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.home {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 33px 23px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.about {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="home">div1</div>
    <div class="about">div2</div>
</div>
```

There are many ways to solve the same problem in CSS however, and which is the best largely depends on the context. There's not really enough information in your question to give a definitive answer, or even to be sure the above will work as expected in your case.